# How to connect grpc server for use in java code?

Tags: java, api, rpc, grpc

I'm working on a project that required me to set up some local nodes that run a grpc server. I have everything working including the grpc server, but I can't figure out / don't understand how to interact with the data..

For example, this is from the documentation "grpc api list"

rpc GetAccount (Account) returns (Account)

or supported command list

GetAccount

I've been reading up on grpc but I'm just stuck.. I've tried running commands through the terminal, nodes, and anything else I could think of.. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here's the documentation I'm following

https://github.com/tronprotocol/wallet-cli

Comment: See https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java.html#generating-client-and-server-code . You will need to integrate `protoc` into your build. What build system are you using to build your code?

Comment: Hi thanks for response, I've been reading up on protobuf, gRPC etc today.

When you say what system are you talking about my IDE (IntelliJ) or how the code is being built, which is with Gradle. I'll have to look at protoc, is that what I use to compile the .proto files to generate some java code? This is the part I'm currently stuck at.

Comment: I meant gradle - since IntelliJ supports building with gradle with a double-click, it's not too disastrous if there's no IntelliJ integration. Yes, protoc is what you use to generate Java code.